# Enviar arquivo de um servidor para outro

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

A aplicação se encontra em um servidor X. A partir de um file upload preciso que o arquivo seja enviado para um servidor Y. Porém não encontro nenhuma solução para isso. A aplicação está em MVC asp net.
Para upload do arquivo para o mesmo servidor utilizo:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {          
        if (file == null)
            ModelState.AddModelError("Arquivo", "Arquivo deve ser válido.");
        else
        {
            string nomeArquivo = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString().Replace("/", "").Replace(":", "") + file.FileName.Substring(file.FileName.LastIndexOf("."));
            string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/arquivos"),
                                       Path.GetFileName(nomeArquivo));
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: O ideal seria X disponibizar uma `Action` de `Controller` que seja um `FileResult`, e Y tenha outra `Action` usando um `HttpClient`. Vou pensar em alguma coisa.

Comment: O problema é que Y não pode ter nenhuma aplicação. Apenas disponibilizaria um diretório.

Comment: o diretório é acessível pelo explorer? por exemplo \\servidor2\docs, ja tentou utilizar apenas `File.WriteAllBytes("\\servidor2\docs\teste.txt")` ?;

Comment: Em web forms eu conseguia fazer assim: string ftpAddres = "ftp://" + username + ":" + ftpPass + "@" + ftpServer + "/" + nome;
                using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
                {
                    webClient.Proxy = null;
                    webClient.UploadData(new Uri(ftpAddres), file.FileBytes);
                }

Comment: Você precisa necessariamente acessar um diretório FTP?

Comment: Sim. Porque é um servidor externo (UOL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o servidor vai fazer o Download, implemente os métodos:

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile()
{
    FtpWebRequest objFTP = null;
    try
    {
        objFTP = FTPDetail("Arquivo.txt");
        objFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

        using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)objFTP.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                int contentLen;

                // Não precisa usar necessariamente uma variável. 
                // Pode ser uma String fixa.
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(variavelQueApontaOndeOArquivoVaiserSalvo, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    byte[] buff = new byte[2048];
                    contentLen = ftpStream.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);

                    while (contentLen != 0)
                    {
                        fs.Write(buff, 0, buff.Length);
                        contentLen = ftpStream.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);
                    }

                    objFTP = null;
                }
            }
        }

        // Aqui você retorna uma View de Sucesso, seu lá como você quer fazer.
        return View();
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        if (objFTP!= null)
        {
            objFTP.Abort();
        }

        throw Ex;
    }
}

private FtpWebRequest FTPDetail(string FileName)
{
    string uri = "";
    string serverIp = "255.255.255.1";
    string Username = "usuario";
    string Password = "teste123";
    uri = "ftp://" + serverIp + "/root/" + FileName;

    FtpWebRequest objFTP;
    objFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(uri));
    objFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
    objFTP.UsePassive = true;
    objFTP.KeepAlive = false;
    objFTP.Proxy = null;
    objFTP.UseBinary = false;
    objFTP.Timeout = 90000;

    return objFTP;
}
```

Agora, se o servidor vai enviar os arquivos pra um servidor FTP, implemente o seguinte:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {          
        if (file == null)
            ModelState.AddModelError("Arquivo", "Arquivo deve ser válido.");
        else
        {
            string nomeArquivo = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString().Replace("/", "").Replace(":", "") + file.FileName.Substring(file.FileName.LastIndexOf("."));
            string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/arquivos"),
                                       Path.GetFileName(nomeArquivo));
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }

        FtpWebRequest objFTP= null;
        try
        {
            objFTP= FTPDetail(path);
            objFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(CompletePath))
            {
                byte[] buff = new byte[fs.Length];
                using (Stream strm = objFTP.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);

                    while (contentLen != 0)
                    {
                        strm.Write(buff, 0, buff.Length);
                        contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);
                    }

                    objFTP = null;
                }
            }

            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            if (objFTP!= null)
            {
                objFTP.Abort();
            }

            throw Ex;
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: O CompleteLocalPath, seria o que? E no return true, está dando erro!

Comment: Deixa eu dar uma traduzida.

Comment: E onde entraria o HttpPostedFileBase file?

Comment: Então, essa resposta é pra um Download de arquivo. Vou colocar o Upload. Peraí.

Comment: @DiegoZanardo Agora eu acho que tem tudo o que você precisa.

Comment: Está dando erro exatamente onde tenho dúvidas. File.OpenRead(CompletePath). No lugar de CompletePath seria por exemplo "255.255.255.1/root/"?

Comment: @DiegoZanardo `ftp://oenderecodouol/root`

Answer (score 1):

No site X, implemente o seguinte:

```
public FileResult DownloadArquivo()
{
    // Abra o arquivo e o transforme em um Array de bytes

    return File(bytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet,
            nomeArquivo + "." + extensao);
}
```

No site Y, implemente o seguinte:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SuaAcao() {
    var client = new HttpClient();

    var uri = new Uri("http://enderecoDoSiteX/ControllerDeDownload/DownloadArquivo");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var bytes = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
        // Faça aqui a lógica de salvar o arquivo
    }

    // Retorne aqui alguma coisa, se precisar.
    // View(), RedirectToAction(), etc.
}
```

Me dê mais informações que eu melhoro a resposta.

Comment: No site Y não posso ter uma aplicação. Apenas a pasta.

Comment: Você consegue ter acesso ao diretório porém não pode rodar uma aplicação la dentro, correto? Seria por acaso algum limite do plano de hospedagem? Não pode adicionar as linhas acima a uma página avulsa do projeto que já está rodando?

Comment: Exatamente @RafaelBarbosa

Comment: Eu vou colocar mais uma resposta com esse cenário.